# Fit image to top of screen, fill width, keep aspect ratio

Tags: ios, image, aspect-ratio

So, what I'm trying to do is have a "banner" at the top of my ViewController. I need the image to stay at the top of the screen, will the full width of the screen and keep its aspect ration when doing so. I'm having a hard time doing this. Here is what I tried:

1. Putting constraints on the top, left and right of the image view.
2. Make the mode `Aspect Fit`

[image]

But this is how it turns out:

[image]

Anyone have any idea how I can force this banner to the top and make it keep its aspect ratio as well?

Comment: Any messages in the console when you run this app and show this view?

Comment: Also, any warnings (red or yellow) in Interface Builder?

Comment: @matt no messages in the console, I have a warning "frame for banner will be different at run time"

Comment: Aha. That warning is important! Click the yellow warning icon and elect to Update Frame. The result will be that it looks the same in Xcode as it does when it runs. Okay, it will now be in the wrong place in both, but at least Xcode won't be misleading you any more! And then you can start to correct your constraints.

Comment: By the way, I am upvoting your question because this is the darned best single screen shot I have ever seen on a constraints question. You packed a huge amount of useful into into one screen shot!

Comment: @matt gotchya, thanks, I can see how it will look now. However, I'm still unsure of how to accomplish the main goal of forcing this to the top and keeping the aspect ratio. Any ideas on this?

Comment: What I'm suggesting is: now that you can see your constraints and the effects they are really having, in Xcode, you should be able to understand why you are not getting what you want, and change the constraints so that you do. The mismatch between frame and constraints was hiding this from you; now you can see what's really going on.

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working: top 0 plus left 0 plus right 0 plus aspect fit should work (works for me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you still lack a constraint. You can add another constraint such as height, or aspect ratio. However, when you add a constraint for aspect ratio, it would fill up the whole screen when in landscape. Unless, you're only using portrait, aspect ratio is fine. If you're both using portrait and landscape, you can use height constraint, and just set the content mode of your image view to aspect fit.

Comment: Oh right, sorry. I thought the orange lines in your screen shot was for ambiguity. It just turns out that its view will be different during runtime because in your storyboard, you have top, left, right margin constraints to 0. If you want to fill the whole width, you can uncheck Constraints to margin.

Comment: I tried using the constraints you used, it worked fine for me.